# inflected languages other than IE and Semitic ones

Tags: linguistic-typology, inflection, morphological-typology

When one looks for examples of inflected languages outside the Indo-European and, perhaps, Semitic domains, it seems that there is none.  Does anyone here know other examples in different linguistic domains?

I just find it very strange that a whole morphological type is entirely confined within the boundaries of just one or two genetic families.

EDIT: by inflected languages I mean not just all those which are not isolating (therefore, including the agglutinating ones), but, more specifically, those which have, for example, comulative inflectional morphemes (among other well-known features)

Comment: An obvious example is any Uralic language. Their morphology is not as transparent as Turkish. What are your criteria for labeling a language agglutinating? For the existence of any two inflectional affixes that can be independently added to a base?

Comment: What about Mongolian though? Dude, what about Basque?

Comment: Basque and Mongolian seem agglutinating to me. But yes, my criteria are not very well-defined. I was trying to investigate the common opinion on this topic. Because if we take it seriously, it's not clear at all what a prototypical inflectional language should be.

Comment: Fusional morphology is rather heavily centred on IE and Semitic languages, that’s true. Most Uralic languages (which are likely the closest relation to IE anyway) are more agglutinating than fusional but do have some fusional traits, and there are others here and there as well, but I’m not aware of any other real fusional _clusters_ on a scale like IE and Semitic.

Comment: Try [Algonquian verb morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algonquian_languages#Grammatical_features) or Uto-Aztecan case systems, for instance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet exactly, looks like we have invented a typology of our own. This is weird, if you think.

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan Not necessarily. There is some evidence that languages tend to very slowly move between typologies like this – going from agglutinative to fusional, for instance, or (as English has more or less done) from fusional to isolating. PIE and Proto-Semitic happened to be fusional at a crucial stage when they started splitting up and spreading out over huge swathes of land, eventually planting the seed for two huge groups of related, fusional languages.

Comment: IE and Semitic language families are very familiar and often used for examples, but there are many other language families in the world that have members with fusional morphology atho it is a relatively unusual feature. The Sko family (PNG); Navajo; and see the multiple exponent chapter and map on [WALS](https://wals.info/chapter/21)

Comment: Related question on [conlang.se]: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/2003/142

Comment: Verbs in Japanese and Korean.

Comment: what about non-Semitic Afro-Asiatic? Amazigh & Middle Egyptian both seem similarly synthetic to many Semitic languages (still more agglutinative than IE typically is). I'm less familiar with them, but Chadic & Cushitic also look similarly inflecting (not sure about Omotic)

Comment: wikipedia also lists some Uralic languages (the Sami languages and Estonian, the latter moreso in certain dialects), as well as NE Caucasian as "weakly" fusional, so depending on strict a definition you want to use they may count